# Isolating function execution in Java

Tags: java, classloader

I have this code:

```
JarByteClassloader loader = new JarByteClassloader(jar);
Class c = loader.loadClass(classToLoad);
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
JarEntryObject jarEntry = (JarEntryObject) c.newInstance();
Response response = jarEntry.execute(module);
```

Is it possible to:

- Limit what the code inside the `execute()` function can acesss, for example code inside the enclosed function should not be able to access other objects from other loaded `JarEntryObject`'s  (isolation)
- And should not be able to access, read or modify application and system variables
- Should not be able to create process/thread that will create Network ports

So what the `execute` function can only access are objects that it created and the `module` object passed into it.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve this via Java Application Isolation API, but I've never used it.

Comment: Did you mean this? https://github.com/chrisgleissner/jisolate